# how can one overwrite the subsequent values in a dataframe grouping with NaNs once a NaN has been observed?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

My question is how can one overwrite the subsequent values in a dataframe grouping once a NaN has been observed?

In the below dataframe, once a `NaN` has been observed for a particular grouping (i.e. same `Pos` and `Stop` values), I'd like to copy down the `NaN`s in a vectorized way to the subsequent rows in the grouping.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'Pos': [np.nan, np.nan,  1.,  1., -1., -1., np.nan, -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1., np.nan, 1.,  np.nan,  1.,  1.], 
'Stop': [np.nan, np.nan, 122.86, 122.86, 128.  , 128.  , np.nan, 128.  , 128, 125.8 , 125.8 , 124.05, np.nan, 123.85, np.nan, 123.85, 123.85]}, 
index = pd.date_range('2022-01-01',periods=17))

df

            Pos    Stop
2022-01-01  NaN     NaN
2022-01-02  NaN     NaN
2022-01-03  1.0  122.86
2022-01-04  1.0  122.86
2022-01-05 -1.0  128.00
2022-01-06 -1.0  128.00
2022-01-07  NaN     NaN
2022-01-08 -1.0  128.00
2022-01-09 -1.0  128.00
2022-01-10 -1.0  125.80
2022-01-11 -1.0  125.80
2022-01-12  1.0  124.05
2022-01-13  NaN     NaN
2022-01-14  1.0  123.85
2022-01-15  NaN     NaN
2022-01-16  1.0  123.85
2022-01-17  1.0  123.85
```

So for example, since `2022-01-07` contains `NaNs` and since `2022-01-08` & `2022-01-09` gave the same values for `Pos` (e.g. -1) and `Stop` (e.g. 128) as the two rows before the `NaN`, I'd like to replace the values in the `2022-01-08` & `2022-01-09` rows with `NaN`s.  Similarly, since `2022-01-15` contains `NaN`s, I'd like to replace the values in `2022-01-16` and `2022-01-17` with `NaN`s.
Note that the rows above the `NaN`s for a particular grouping should remain unchanged.

I tried using a `groupby` but was unsucessful.  Therefore, my question is how can one overwrite the subsequent values in a dataframe grouping with `NaN`s once a `NaN` has been observed?

Expected output is below:

```
df1
            Pos    Stop
2022-01-01  NaN     NaN
2022-01-02  NaN     NaN
2022-01-03  1.0  122.86
2022-01-04  1.0  122.86
2022-01-05 -1.0  128.00
2022-01-06 -1.0  128.00
2022-01-07  NaN     NaN
2022-01-08  NaN     NaN
2022-01-09  NaN     NaN
2022-01-10 -1.0  125.80
2022-01-11 -1.0  125.80
2022-01-12  1.0  124.05
2022-01-13  NaN     NaN
2022-01-14  1.0  123.85
2022-01-15  NaN     NaN
2022-01-16  NaN     NaN
2022-01-17  NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Can you provide an expected output for the above dataset?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal Added expected output. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way using `pandas.DataFrame.interpolate` and `where`:

```
df2 = df.interpolate()
m = df["Pos"].notna()
m = df2.assign(tmp=m).groupby(["Pos", "Stop"])["tmp"].cummin().eq(1)
new_df = df.where(m)

print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
            Pos    Stop
2022-01-01  NaN     NaN
2022-01-02  NaN     NaN
2022-01-03  1.0  122.86
2022-01-04  1.0  122.86
2022-01-05 -1.0  128.00
2022-01-06 -1.0  128.00
2022-01-07  NaN     NaN
2022-01-08  NaN     NaN
2022-01-09  NaN     NaN
2022-01-10 -1.0  125.80
2022-01-11 -1.0  125.80
2022-01-12  1.0  124.05
2022-01-13  NaN     NaN
2022-01-14  1.0  123.85
2022-01-15  NaN     NaN
2022-01-16  NaN     NaN
2022-01-17  NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Great solution.  Curious if you know why the lline `df2.assign(tmp=m).groupby(["Pos", "Stop"])["tmp"].cummin()` produces -1 for the first two rows?

Comment: @jgg I think it is a bug on pandas :P Let me look into it further